# Is it possible to replace EditForm.aspx for a Content Type with a custom aspx form page?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-type

I am trying to create an aspx page for uploading a document to a document library where the documents are associated with a content type.   (Rather than using the standard EditForm.aspx)  My efforts thus far have not been successful.

As a first step in my **HelloWorld**, I would like to get my aspx edit page to show up when I upload a file to a document library.

I have used SPD to set the Edit page for my content type to /MyForms/MyEditForm.aspx

I then go to SP and select "libraries">MyLibrary, selecting "Library Tools"> Documents in the ribbon, I click the "Upload" button.   This displays the Upload.aspx form.   Browsing to a file and clicking OK, causes the normal EditForm.aspx for to be displayed.

This is the problem.   I thought that by using SPD to set the edit form of the content type associated with that document library I would see MyEditForm, not the standard EditForm.aspx file here.

I put MyEditForm.aspx into the FormServerTemplates/Forms/ directory inside of a new dir called "MyForms".

There is clearly something wrong with my basic approach.  Any advice on how to adjust my tactics would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Trey Carroll

Answer (score 1):

From what you are saying I think you just need to make your custom edit form the default. In SPD, go to the document library and select the MyEditForm.aspx. You should see "Set as Default" light up in the ribbon. After setting it as default it should show Yes in the default column in the Forms list on the document library settings page.